# Как узнать семейство загруженного шрифта?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, html5

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста, как узнать семейство загруженного шрифта? Шрифт загружается через input file. Шрифт это или нет можно узнать функцией imageloadfont(), например. Я только этот способ успел узнать. А можно ли средствами php или js узнать семейство загруженного шрифта?

Comment: Прежде всего, у шрифтов есть разные форматы, каждый со своими метаданными. Вот пример для нахождения семейства ttf шрифта: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668901/php-how-to-read-title-of-font-from-ttf-file/5669037#comment-6469917

Comment: Или библиотека тут: https://github.com/PhenX/php-font-lib

Comment: То есть всё это только для ttf? Мне бы для eot тоже нужно. Но библиотека и класс на первый взгляд прикольные.

Comment: Библиотека вроде как и eot поддерживает.

Comment: А, и правда, мельком глянул, не качая просто, спасибо большое.